# Как лучше слить изменения?

Tags: git

Как лучше сливать изменения из одной ветки в другую если в ней много коммитов? Я имею ввиду что если просто сделать `merge` то все вольется одним коммитом и когда я удалю ту ветку из которой сливал то я потом просто не найду концов. Единственное что приходит в голову это `cherry-pick` каждого отдельного коммита, но это муторно... Есть еще идеи?

Comment: `git rebase interactive` и сквош всех коммитов в один

Comment: Ну а поребейзить мастер на сливаемую ветку и потом смержить чем плохо? Получите те же коммиты прямо от свежего мастера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кажется я плохо знаю как работает `merge`. Почему-то я думал что он всегда все сливает одним коммитом, а сейчас слил - и все нормально зашло отдельными коммитами. Ну тогда вопрос решен.

Answer (score 2):

`git cherry-pick` можно делать для диапазона коммитов, указывая их ID, например:

```
git cherry-pick d467740 de906d4
```

Comment: Проверил сегодня этот способ. Не особо понял... Ну во первых у меня были конфликты слияния которые я порешал. Теперь оно предлагает закомитить, но я не понимаю зачем? Я имею ввиду я что хотел видеть? Что все коммиты из другой ветки перенесутся по одному в нужную мне. А сейчас я вижу по сути тот же результат что и при обычном `merge` - все слилось в один коммит.